# Rake cannot run Rspec specs in Docker/Rails/Postgres setup (but web app works fine)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, docker

Is there a special step or configuration needed to get Rails (3.2.21) test database (eg, Rspec specs) working under Docker when using the Heroku-docker solution?

I'm using Docker Toolkit (the Docker Quickstart Terminal) to run my Heroku app locally, and everything *except* running specs is working.

This works:

```
docker-compose run web rake db:reset
```

And the web app works, reading and writing the database with all seed value loaded.

However any command to create or use the test database fails:

```
docker-compose run web rake db:test:prepare
docker-compose run web rake db:test:load    
docker-compose run web rake spec
docker-compose run web bundle exec rake spec
```

all throw the error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: role "root" does not exist
```

I'm using the Heroku postgres image, with an app.json that looks like:

```
{
  "name": "My App",
  "description": "Localized Docker Setup",
  "image": "hrails200",
  "addons": [
    "heroku-postgresql"
  ]
}
```

*(hrails200 is the heroku/ruby image modified to use Ruby 2.0.0)*

and the docker-compose.yml file ends with:

```
herokuPostgresql:
  image: postgres
```

and the web and worker have a links entry pointing to Postgres:

```
  links:
    - herokuPostgresql
```

My config/database.yml looks like:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: docker_mondo_dev

test:
  <<: *default
  database: docker_mondo_test
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you connect to Postgres, it defaults to the current Unix user (`$USER`). Under Docker, you are 'root' by default. However, Postgres does not have any user named 'root' by default. Instead, the superuser is named 'postgres'.

I think that your web app is specifying a database user name, and your test is not. You might try setting the `PGUSER` environment variable to `postgres`.

Comment: Thank you Nathaniel, the solution seems to be to invoke it thusly: `docker-compose run web rake spec PGUSER=postgres RAILS_ENV=test`